# Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error: R

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I was working with my app just fine until a few days ago, when I installed a Virtual Box on my Windows 8 and then installed a Ubuntu server in it.  I don't know if that is the cause but it happened on the same day.  Maybe it's a proxy server error, but I have no idea about how to go about that.

I have searched thru the Github and S.O. pages about other errors like this, but all those fixes don't work for me. I am able to interact with other APIs (like Blockspring) inside RStudio and I have worked through [Hadley's example](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth1-twitter.r) and I was able to successfully authenticate, but whenever I run this:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret,Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret)
```

in RStudio (selected either 1 or 2) I get the error:

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

Here is my code:

```
library(twitteR)    
library(ROAuth)    
Consumer_Key <-"0eHKFqEa7zwOiPIxnbIvP05R0"
Consumer_Secret <- "wJL4usoL97pBhwAj5nizPQ4X4LycCUGPKj8IXo5dQB8GB8dVfQ"
Access_Token <- "2711268549-vTrxBE1Ihyk4iNqA3jSaEfiJYUBgDCDRhbjv36j"
Access_Token_Secret <- "eCstykgjkTloQUzErvxPONX852lVKUkfcW0xhh85NmAu6"

setup_twitter_oauth(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret,Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret)
```

I have also ...

- updated to the latest version of R (3.2.1)
- installed latest version of 'httr'
- set my Twitter app callback URL to http://127.0.0.1.1410
- regenerated new credentials (twice)
- created a new app (shown below)
- disabled my firewall

I can supply more `Sys.getenv()` info if needed. I have to have this working by tomorrow, so any quick help will be great.  THANKS!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bit_1.1-12    httr_1.0.0    rjson_0.2.15  R6_2.0.1      magrittr_1.5    DBI_0.3.1     tools_3.2.1   curl_0.9      bit64_0.9-4   stringi_0.5-5
[11] stringr_1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

With The latest version of R, `httr_1.0.0` gets installed by default. However, `twitter_1.1.8` performs better with `httr_0.6.0`. So, u can try installing `httr_0.6.0` and also don't forget to restart your R session.

Comment: check this out, if you haven't yet.. [link] (https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues/90)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the httr's dependencies :

```
install.packages("httr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

And check YES (y) to:

```
Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
```

Cheers